# How to override/ignore WARFileName in cxf endpoint configuration which uses servlet transport

Tags: java, servlets, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse

I am exposing a camel cxf webservice using servlet transport.The packaged camel application war file name is samplewebservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

I am using Jboss fuse 6.3,Jboss EAP 6.4

Web xml configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
           version="2.5">
    <display-name>ssl-cxf</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:META-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> 

</web-app>
```

Based upon the configurations in my application the endpoint is published as below:

https://localhost:8443/samplewebservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/authentication?wsdl

After reading the documention:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.1/html/deploying_into_a_web_server/DeployCamelWS

As per the servlet-mapping/url-pattern i understand the url is published as below.

http://Host:Port/WARFileName/URLPattern

I do not want WARFileName to be included in the published endpoint url.

is there any possibility i can override/ignore the WARFileName parameter with some other pattern instead of war file name?

Comment: There is likely some configuration on WildFly/EAP where you can say in the web.xml or some jboss.xml file what the name of the context-path should be. I have done that in the past with other JEE servers. For root path (/) you may not be able to use that, as it may be "reserved" for the app server itself.

Comment: On EAP you can configure the context-path in WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/my-context-root</context-root>
</jboss-web>

If you want a context-root of '/' you can deploy your application as ROOT.war.

Comment: Hi James,it is working.Is there any server level configuration which i can specific in standalone xml. instead of adding jboss-web.xml in each and every camel cxf webservice application?

Answer (score 1):

War file  name is usually the context path. If your war file has root level(/), then there is no need explicit name. There should be only one root app per instance

Comment: Hi Panneer,I have updated the web xml configuration.Which parameter configuration determines the root level (/) of the war file?